# Gambler's Ruin Problem with Simple Solution - Different Approach

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, gambling

> What is the probability that symmetric simple random walk starting at the origin reaches $−1$ before it reaches $9$? Briefly explain your answer.
>
> > Solution: This is $p = 1$ gambler's ruin with states $0, 1, . . . , 10$ but the states have been relabelled $−1, 0, . . . , 9$. The answer is $\frac{9}{10}$ because state 0 is one tenth of the way from $−1$ to $9$.

Unfortunately, I used a different and rather clumsy way to approach this question.

My attempt was not successful but I was wondering if there is anyone who can tell me how to go further with it and arrive at the solution.

---

My attempt:
I drew it out like birth and death process with 11 states. With $-1$ and $9$ having the probability of returning to itself as 1 (absorbing state).
Let's $P(X_i)$ be probability to reach $-1$ before reaching $9$, starting from $i$.

Then I listed out $$P(X_0) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}P(X_1)$$
$$P(X_i) = \frac{1}{2}\left(P(X_{i-1}) + P(X_{i+1})\right) \ \ \text{ for } i \in\{1,2,3,...7\}$$

$$P(X_8) = \frac{1}{2}P(X_7) + 0$$

There are 9 equations and 9 unknowns. We should be able to calculate the result. However, how to go from here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** The equations
$$
P\left(X_{i+1}\right) - 2P\left(X_i\right) + P\left(X_{i-1}\right)=0\ \ \ \mathrm{for}\ i=1,2,\dots,7
$$
constitute a second-order linear recurrence whose general solution is $\ P\left(X_n\right) = a + bn\ $ for $\ n=0,1, \dots, 8\ $, and some constants $\ a\ $ and $\ b\ $.  The boundary conditions, $\  P\left(X_0\right) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}P\left(X_1\right)\ $, and  $\ P\left(X_8\right) = \frac{1}{2}P\left(X_7\right)\ $, give you two linear equations to solve for the values of $\ a\ $ and $\ b\ $.

Answer (score 2):

The equation
$$P(X_i) = \frac{1}{2}\left(P(X_{i-1}) + P(X_{i+1})\right) \: \: \:  \; (*)$$
holds for $i \in\{0,2,3,...8\}$ since $P(X_{-1})=1$ and $P(X_9)=0$.
Write $$Q_i=P(X_i)-P(X_{i-1})$$ for $i=0,1,\ldots,9$.
Then by doubling (*) and subtracting $P(X_{i-1}) + P(X_{i})$ from both sides, we get that
$$Q_i = Q_{i+1}  $$
holds for $i \in\{0,2,3,...8\}$. Since $\sum_{i=0}^9 Q_i=-1$ we conclude that $Q_i=-1/10$ for all $i$.  In particular $P(X_0)=1+Q_0=9/10$.